# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream

Tags: solr

I have installed Apache Solr with Tomcat and my `/solr/admin` is working fine. But when I try to issue  `/solr/update` I am getting the following error. What could be the reason?

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: missing content stream

Comment: Can you post the update XML you are sending to the server? How are you posting? Using curl, using an application, using your browser?

Comment: I try to run ./post.sh comes with the exampledoc. But it says curl not found. while I try to hit like http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-1.4.1/update, I got the 400 error with content stream missing.
and this is my post.sh

FILES=$*
URL=http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-1.4.1/update

for f in $FILES; do
  echo Posting file $f to $URL
  curl $URL --data-binary @$f -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8' 
  echo
done

#send the commit command to make sure all the changes are flushed and visible
curl $URL --data-binary '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'
echo

Comment: I have fixed it with 
java -Durl=http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-1.4.1/update -jar post.jar *.xml

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/solr/update` will look for any input documents to be indexed. Running plain `/solr/update` will cause this exception since there is no input for it. The easiest way to run it is like,

```
java -Durl=localhost:8080/<your apache solr context path, mostly solr>/update -jar post.jar *.xml
```

This can also happen through SolrJ/spring-data-solr if you try to persist an empty collection of documents.

So `solrClient.add(new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>(), 10000);`

would also cause the error.

Comment: Note for others: This can also happen through SolrJ/spring-data-solr if you try to persist an empty collection of documents.

Comment: “missing content stream” can also occur once you post an empty list object using SOLRJ

Answer (score 13):

If you add commit parameter i.e. `?commit=true`, it will work