# What is the significance of the "missing content stream" exception in SolrCore?

Tags: java, solr

I have seen [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727088/org-apache-solr-common-solrexception-missing-content-stream) questions on this topic. However, they do not address the general nature of what exactly a "content stream" is.

1. What is a "content stream" in solr, and what is the significance of this message? For example, often when we get a CONNECTION FAILURE in an SQL database, it means simply that there is no route to the database server.  In this same idiom: what is the meaning of a missing "content stream" when we are writing to Solr?
2. What do we need to verify in our java apps before writing to a Solr Core?

Answer (score 4):

1. You are using the Solr Update request handler that expects an http POST stream of XML documents to be sent. So in this case if you are not passing any documents to be posted when calling the url, you will get the "missing content stream message".
2. In your Java apps you need to verify that you are passing an appropriate content stream and parameters to Solr. You can get more details on the [UpdateXMLMessages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) wiki page.

Also, you might want to consider using the [SolrJ Java client](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) to write and query the Solr index.

Comment: When you say "appropriate" .... does this mean that a missing content stream --> your java solr client is creating null/bad data ?

Comment: If you follow the SolrJ wiki for creating documents to upload using the SolrJ client, I doubt that you would be uploading null/bad data, but it could be posible. If you have a code sample of what you are doing when you experience this error, it would be helpful to add that to the question.

Comment: “missing content stream” can also occur once you post an empty list object using SOLRJ

Answer (score 1):

1. content stream = Is the data you submit to Solr
2. You need to verify that your content Stream is in accordance with the Solr schema . Example : You are submitting value "name" of Type String from your java client and in Solr Schema there is a field "name" of type String. You need to verify the username and the password  are correct ,to authenticate to solr if such is needed.