# Keep getting a "missing content stream" error using php and curl to post XML

Tags: php, xml, curl, solr

I am trying to get php to post to the solr server when the content of a wiki article changes. This is SOLR version 4.4.0, PHP 5.3.3, CURL 7.19.7.

Anybody have any ideas? 
Thanks,
Pete.

**Here is the PHP Code**

```
$header = array("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://wiki.XXXXX.com:8080/solr/update?wt=json&indent=true");        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Here is the error**

```
DEBUG - 2014-05-07 09:18:22.028; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; PRE_UPDATE FINISH {indent=true&wt=json&<add><doc>
<field type='string'+name%3D'segment'>100000000</field>%0a<field+type%3D'string'+name%3D'digest'>ed226ec873a622e54e26c0eb31f18e2f</field>%0a<field+type%3D'float'+name%3D'boost'>0</field></field>%0a<field+type%3D'text_general'+name%3D'content'>*+goofball%0a*+goofy</field>%0a<field+type%3D'text_general'+name%3D'title'>SolrIndexArticle+Test</field>%0a<field+type%3D'string'+name%3D'author'>Polsen</field>%0a<field+type%3D'long'+name%3D'_version_'></field>%0a</doc></add>%0a<commit+waitFlush%3D'false'+waitSearcher%3D'false'/>%0a}
INFO  - 2014-05-07 09:18:22.028; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={indent=true&wt=json&<add><doc>
<field type='string'+name%3D'segment'>100000000</field>%0a<field+type%3D'string'+name%3D'digest'>ed226ec873a622e54e26c0eb31f18e2f</field>%0a<field+type%3D'float'+name%3D'boost'>0</field>%0a<field+type%3D'url'+name%3D'host'>HOST URL</field>%0a<field+type%3D'url'+name%3D'url'>URL ID</field>%0a<field+type%3D'url'+name%3D'id'>URL ID</field>%0a<field+type%3D'text_general'+name%3D'content'>*+goofball%0a*+goofy</field>%0a<field+type%3D'text_general'+name%3D'title'>SolrIndexArticle+Test</field>%0a<field+type%3D'string'+name%3D'author'>Polsen</field>%0a<field+type%3D'long'+name%3D'_version_'></field>%0a</doc></add>%0a<commit+waitFlush%3D'false'+waitSearcher%3D'false'/>%0a} {} 0 12
ERROR - 2014-05-07 09:18:22.029; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: <strong>missing content stream</strong>
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1904)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:659)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**Here is the PHP error log output:**

==> /data/php_errors.log <==

```
[07-May-2014 09:18:22] curr exited okay
[07-May-2014 09:18:22] Data returned...
[07-May-2014 09:18:22] ------------------------------------
[07-May-2014 09:18:22] HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 07 May 2014 13:18:22 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":12},
  "error":{
    "msg":"missing content stream",
    "code":400}}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Though this solution has been given in comments before, I'd like to emphasize it in a separate answer here.*

Solr obviously returns "missing content stream" on requests providing file **without committing**. Returned error is confusing for content file was actually given.

I was analyzing similar case in using Solarium client doing extractOnly requests. After trying to switch client-side adapters and after ensuring requests are including selected file I finally succeeded by adding `$request->setCommit( true );`.

Answer (score 0):

"Missing content stream" from a post to Solr means that you sent an empty document or no documents at all to Solr. In this case you appear to be trying to update something in Solr - however according to this error you are not passing it anything. I also don't see anything in your code that includes or points to a document to update -

These previous discussions may help:

[What is the significance of the "missing content stream" exception in SolrCore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301720/what-is-the-significance-of-the-missing-content-stream-exception-in-solrcore)

Comment: I am sending the content of the document as part of the PUT. You can see the content in the error response from the server. Or am I misinterpreting what that data actually is? I think it is the content of the document that is supposed to be indexed. There is no physical document on the server to index.

Comment: Can you add the content to your code listing? It's more difficult to try to parse it out from an error message, plus it's more helpful to see exactly what you posted in. I don't see any </doc> or </add> in your returned error message but that may be just because it's stripped out in the error log.

Comment: `<add>
<doc>
<field name='digest'>1d0166376a3238ad46826ab1ea8ed186</field>
<field name='url'>http://wiki.XXXX.com/sandbox/index.php/SolrIndexArticle_Test</field>
<field name='id'>http://wiki.XXXXX.com/sandbox/index.php/SolrIndexArticle_Test</field>
<field name='content'>* goofedball
* goofball
* peanut butter
* flimflam
* this is a change
* gibberish
* new</field>
<field name='title'>SolrIndexArticle Test</field>
<field name='author'>Polsen</field>
</doc>
</add>
<commit waitFlush='false' waitSearcher='false'/>`

Comment: I added the "commit=true" parameter to my url and now I no longer get the "missing content stream" error BUT the content still does not seem to be searchable. Here is the response I get: `{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":31}}`

Comment: What version of Solr are you using? waitFlush has been deprecated. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages . If you are looking to search for this immediately I'd try a softcommit.

Comment: I have departed from using my own code and I am now using SolrPhpClient. It seems to be working although I did have to remove the "waitflush" from the raw data sent in order for it to work.